# access to attribute through attrs.val or attrs.$set(attname, val)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

What is the difference between 2 way of setting attributes from directive(or other places)

(environment):

```
angular.module('module', [])
  .directive('directive', [ function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope:    true,
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      ...
```

between:

```
     attrs.skipWatchValue = true;
```

and

```
     attrs.$set( 'skip-watch-value', true );
```

(it seems that the second one doesnt't work at all now...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a single difference between both the syntax that, writing `attrs.$set( 'skip-watch-value', true );` will also modify the DOM element (see by inspecting element) and sets the value while `attrs.skipWatchValue = true;` will not modify the DOM element.